# jquery data table not working properly through ajax post request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

in data table , i have to show the table data through ajax request, but it is not working properly,
ajax request has post method that returns j son data , code i have given below gets the data to console but it doesn't populate in to the table.
please have a look in my code and help me out ! thanks in advance.

j query data table code:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {
            var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings); // <--- create new api object using settings object
            $.ajax({
                url: 'api/v1/reconcile-data',
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    pageNumber: api.page(), // <---- get page number
                    pageSize: api.page.len(), //<--- get page length
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log("this is datat" + response.content)
                    return response.content;
                },


            });
        },
        columns: [
            {content: 'accountNo'},
            {content: 'refNo'},
            {content: 'amount'},
            {content: 'mainCode'},

        ]
    });
});
```

Json Data :-

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "accountNo": "4321xxxxx5011",
            "refNo": "23456191211",
            "cardNo": "418121xxxxxxx431",
            "adviceType": null,
            "amount": "11000.0",
            "cardType": null,
            "description": "NA",
            "drCrType": null,
            "reason": null,
            "transactionTypeId": null,
            "mainCode": "189490988",
            "traceId": null,
            "txnAmount": null,
            "tdsName": "EJ",
            "rcName": null,
            "colorId": null,
            "txnDate": null,
            "cdate": "2020-12-20T05:54:42.015+0000"
        },
        {
            "accountNo": "4321xxxxx5011",
            "refNo": "23456191211",
            "cardNo": "418121xxxxxxx431",
            "adviceType": null,
            "amount": "11000.0",
            "cardType": null,
            "description": null,
            "drCrType": null,
            "reason": null,
            "transactionTypeId": null,
            "mainCode": "189490988",
            "traceId": "210111",
            "txnAmount": null,
            "tdsName": "CBS",
            "rcName": null,
            "colorId": null,
            "txnDate": null,
            "cdate": null
        }
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "sorted": true,
            "unsorted": false,
            "empty": false
        },
        "offset": 0,
        "pageSize": 2,
        "pageNumber": 0,
        "paged": true,
        "unpaged": false
    },
    "totalElements": 101,
    "last": false,
    "totalPages": 51,
    "size": 2,
    "number": 0,
    "sort": {
        "sorted": true,
        "unsorted": false,
        "empty": false
    },
    "numberOfElements": 2,
    "first": true,
    "empty": false
}
```

Html:-

```
 <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>name</th>
                                <th>address</th>
                                <th> books</th>
                                <th>home addres</th>

                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
```

image of my datatable:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDdL4.png)

Comment: You are making a jQuery ajax call _inside_ the Datatables built-in Ajax call. Have a look at the [documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax)

Comment: When you use server-side processing, DataTables _automatically_ handles sending relevant data to the server, every time you change pages, or perform a sort or a filter. That data includes "current page" and "page size". You do not need to handle that, yourself. See [this list of "sent parameters"](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters) for details.

Comment: Your JSON data contains an array called `content`. That is the starting point needed by DataTables so that it can iterate over your rows of table data. You need to tell DataTables that this is the entry point into your array by using [`dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc).